# Grid with TestFolders and TestCase hierarchy

Tags: extjs, rally

I need a application where my testcases are displayed by TestFolders, following the testFolders hierarchy. For example :

```
TestFolder1
- SubTestFolder1.1
-- TestCase111
-- TestCase112
-- TestCase113
- SubTestFolder1.2
-- TestCase121
-- TestCase222
TestFolder2
-- TestCase21
-- TestCase22
```

With expandable TestFolders... I do found some exemples for UserStories but it is not applicable because it uses specific objects as rallyuserstorytree, I understand I should build my own tree model ? But I'm beginner to Rally and I don't really understand how to do it. The inline help as no such exemples...

This gave me a blank page, my callback is never loaded, and it cause an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" that I don't understand...

```
var myTreeStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStore', {
    model : 'TestFolder',
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, data, success){
            console.log('  in load calback');
            //process data
        },
        scope: this,
    },
    autoLoad : true,
    fetch: [ 'FormattedID', 'TestCases' ,'Description'],
    limit: records_nbr,
    remoteSort : true ,
    sorters: ['FormattedID'],
    pagesize: records_nbr,
    autoLoad: true, 
});
```

I tried another way, this code for exemple :

```
_createTree: function(){
    var me = this ;
    var myTree = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        itemID: 'myTree',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'rallytree',
            topLevelModel: 'TestFolder',
            childModelTypeForRecordFn: function(record){
                if(record.get('Children') && record.get('Children').length > 0){
                    return 'TestCase';
                } else {
                    return 'TestFolder';
                }
            },
            givenAParentRecordWhatIsTheAttributeConnectingAChildToThisParentFn: function(record){
                if(record.get('Children') && record.get('Children').length > 0){
                    return 'Parent';
                } else {
                    return 'WorkProduct';
                }
            },
            canExpandFn: function(record){
                return true;
            }
        }
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom,
    });
    this.add(myTree);
},
```

But it only display the top-level TestFolders without the possibility to expand them.  Where can I find a exemple of an application displaying TestFolders and TestCases in a hierarchcal grid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStore included in 2.0rc2 is still pretty raw.  We are currently working on better support for hierarchical grid data.  More than likely the example you posted above was designed to work with WSAPI version 1.x, where it was still possible to retrieve child collections in one request.  2.0rc2 enforces the use of WSAPI 2.x, which returns a collection summary object instead (and requires an additional request to populate).

Something like the following should work better for you:

```
record.get('TestCases') && record.get('TestCases').Count > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I can retrieve the collections like that. But I can not mix Sub-TestFolders and TestCases under the same TestFolder with a RallyTree... I will use basic TreePanel.

Answer (score 1):

Answer myself...

The 2nd example is based on what you found in SDK source code as example (https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/sdk-debug.js). But the sdk is bugged or the example is wrong, because it checks

```
if(record.get('Children') && record.get('Children').length > 0){
```

and whatever the TestFolder is empty or not, the `Children` property is ALWAYS an empty string. For a given object, there is no way to know if it has children or not loking only his properties.

If I replace the previous line with something like

```
if(record.get('_type') === 'testfolder'){
```

It works, but I still don't see TestCases, because for a given TestFolder object, I have no means to know looking his properties if it has testcases attached... As for the "Children" attribute, the `TestCases` property is also ALWAYS an empty string. Another bug ? I don't find the way to submit bugs to RallyDev :-(